# Why thread() doesn't entering function?

Tags: c++

```
void * bubbleSort( int * data){
 ....
}

  int main(){
   for ( int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i ++){
        thread sort(bubbleSort, data);
        sort.join();
    }   
  }
```

I use Dev-C++ . and I debug.

When it runs `thread sort(bubbleSort,data)`,It doesn't entring bubbleSort function

It Show me:

[image]

After, it executes `sort.join();`

It never run in ,I don't know why.

Comment: The debugger is tracing the main thread; when the new thread launches, you'd have to switch to it to trace execution inside that thread.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Can you tell me how to do ?

Comment: @ShadowRanger or give me some websites

Comment: Put a print statement into `bubbleSort()` to check if it called. Btw your code is single threaded convoluted way. Put all threads in a vector and call join on all of them after the loop.

Comment: @Slava Thx. maybe my code is wrong in my bubble sort